# how to get yii2/admin menu

Tags: php, yii2-advanced-app

i am new in yii2 and using advance template .

i am using yii2/admin for roles , permission. but i can't get the menu manage  using yii2/admin

the image for the menu manage

[like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V7t9q.png)

how to get this interface for manage menu

i read  [this](https://github.com/mdmsoft/yii2-admin/blob/master/docs/guide/using-menu.md)

when i run

> (index.php?r=admin/menu)

i got an error

```
Invalid Configuration – yii\base\InvalidConfigException
The table does not exist: {{%menu}}
```

how to create menu table.
i got a migration file from

**vendor/mdmsoft/yii2-admin/migrations/m140602_111327_create_menu_table.php**

how to run this migration

Answer (score 1, accepted):

please go through with this link [MDM Yii2-admin Basic Configuration](https://github.com/mdmsoft/yii2-admin/blob/master/docs/guide/configuration.md)

add in backend/congif/main.php

```
'modules' => [
        'admin' => [
            'class' => 'mdm\admin\Module',
            'layout' => 'left-menu', // it can be '@path/to/your/layout'.
            'controllerMap' => [
                'assignment' => [
                    'class' => 'mdm\admin\controllers\AssignmentController',
                    'userClassName' => 'common\models\User',
                    'idField' => 'id'
                ],
            ],
            'menus' => [
                'assignment' => [
                    'label' => 'Grand Access' // change label
                ],
                'route' => null, // disable menu route
            ]
        ],
    ],
```

for run migration use this, through cmd/terminal

yii migrate --migrationPath=@mdm/admin/migrations